# insertMany method returns insertedIds in an Object instead of Array in Mongoose 5

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Recently I update Mongoose from 4.x to 5.x, the code is broken at insertMany return value.

Before update, the insertedIds is the key in the return object and the value is an Array which contains all the inserted ObjectIds like

```
[ObjectId1, ObjectId2].
```

After update, the value of insertedIds is an Object like this:

```
{ 
  1: ObjectId1, 
  2: ObjectId2 
}
```

I have to use Object.values to convert it to Array.
I tried insertMany method in Mongo shell, the insertedIds is Array.

Did I miss something during the upgrade?

Comment: The documentation says it should be an array, either the mongodb documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/, or the W3School documentation https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

The mongoose 5.x supports node-mongodb-native 3.x driver which have results in the `insertedIds` key with the format you are seeing right now. You need to make some code changes as node-mongodb 2.x driver returns result in the `list` but not 3.x which returns a `map`.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a documentation stating this? The mongodb documentation says it should be an array.